# how to configure XsltUpdateRequestHandler

Tags: solr

I'm looking for a simple example of configuring XsltUpdateRequestHandler.

The SOLR config in 3.4.0 is minimal:

```
<!-- XSLT Update Request Handler
   Transforms incoming XML with stylesheet identified by tr=
-->
<requestHandler name="/update/xslt"
               startup="lazy"
               class="solr.XsltUpdateRequestHandler" />
```

And the SOLR wiki page is virtually non-existent ("TODO: Write a better documentation"):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltUpdateRequestHandler

I guess I really want to know how to point to a specific XSL file, because I find the line "Transforms incoming XML with stylesheet identified by tr=" a bit cryptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add an XSL style sheet to the `solr/conf/xslt` directory.

You can then use the XsltUpdateRequestHandler, and specify that stylesheet when you index the document.

For example:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/xslt?commit=true&tr=rss2solr.xsl" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary @blogrss.xml
```

For details, a [nice article](http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/technical-articles/whitepapers/programmers-guide-open-source-search-search-whats-new-apache-solr-lucene-3-4) explains in detail. (Free to download)

Comment: +1 for the 'nice' article --have been trying to figure out how best I could update my structured XML files